# Google Analytics 4 migration records half page views than GA3

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

We have noticed a discrepancy in the page views between GA4 and GA3. In GA4, the page views are nearly half of what we see in GA3, but surprisingly, our conversions remain almost identical in both versions. Any insights into why we might be observing this difference in page views while conversions are consistent?

I need to insepect our website why it is recording half the page views on GA4 or double the page views on GA3

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you explain the metrics you are comparing (exact names) in GA3 and GA4?Aalso if possible paste the site link to check. In GA4, try to match the count of page_view event with GA3 pageviews.

Comment: Here is website address animascoaching.com @Tushar. I can not see to send you attachments

Comment: For GA3 (UA) you are sending double (duplicate) pageviews mate, I just checked on your website. GA4 looks fine. In short, GA4 should be more accurate as you had issues in your GA3 tracking.

Comment: I have attached two images in description of the post above. How I am sending double page views how can I verify this. Also on conversions I can see fine. @Tushar

Comment: Added in the answer, the events are working fine I checkd

Answer (score 1):

Based on the website link (animascoaching.com) you have pasted, You are sending double pageviews for GA3, which means GA3 pageview metric would be inflated.

GA4 tracking looks fine. GA4 should be more accurate in your case, and if it's showing half of the metric, then that's the right metric.

---

How to check for double pageviews for GA3?

Option 1: Legacy Tag Assistant extension.

[image]

---

Option 2:

Network Requests and filter by `collect?v=1` or `pageview`

[image]

Comment: I can see on 1 page view request using Tag Assistant Legacy @Tushar

Comment: @Shabbir I disagree, I can even see two pageview network requests on your website

Comment: Thanks @Tushar but how can I check what is generating two page views on single click I can not find anything

Comment: @Shabbir When I go in your website code, I can see both `gtag` hardcoded  and `GTM` installed. You need to either ask your devs to remove this line gtag("config",gaID,configuration)` or you need to stop sending pageviews from GTM.

Comment: Ok I am developer myself let me find and remove gtag and check. Thanks @Tushar

Comment: If/when this solves your issue, please upvote and accept the answer mate.

Comment: Sure I will @Tushar. I am finding gtag but can not see any in code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254365/discussion-between-tushar-and-shabbir).

Comment: Another clue for double tracking like this is that the bounce rate is very low.

Comment: what does this mean @TonyMcCreath

Comment: If you look at the bounce rates for your site. If it is low, say under 10%, there is a good chance you have multiple tags on your site. This is because every visit causes multiple page views which means it is not a bounce.